# How should I pass application-specific configuration parameters to a WSGI app?

Tags: configuration, wsgi

CherryPy, uwsgi, gunicorn, and others all have different ways to pass parameters for the container, such as port, number of threads, etc. However, my app has its own domain-specific configuration parameters that the container knows nothing about, naturally. I can think of several ways to get that information in, such as file in a well-known location, environment variables (gasp!), etc.

Is there a standard or preferred way to do it? Something in the wsgi protocol that I haven't been able to find? Some option like "--user"? I haven't been able to find "best practices" advice on this.

Comment: The WSGI specification provides nothing to help you with this.

Comment: Best practices, then? What do other people do?